# Running median last n days group by user. BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

| date | user_id | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-10-05 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-10-09 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-10-15 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-10-10 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-10-20 | 2 | 5 |

And I want to add column with median revenue for the last 5 days group by user_id. Desired output should looks like this:

| date | user_id | revenue | median_last_5_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-10-05 | 1 | 2 | 2.5 |
| 2021-10-09 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-10-16 | 1 | 3 | NULL |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | 2 | NULL |
| 2021-10-02 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-10-03 | 2 | 3 | 2.5 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-10-10 | 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-10-20 | 2 | 5 | NULL |

Can I produce this with SQL BigQuery?
Thanks for helping me)

Comment: Something like: `PERCENTILE_CONT(x, 0.5) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) RANGE BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` I'm not sure exactly how to best express the range in Big Query though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `PERCENTILE_CONT` or `PERCENTILE_DISC` to get the median will not work  on these conditions as `window_frame_clause` are not allowed in [Navigation functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#navigation_function_concepts).

Try this approach,

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MEDIAN(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT
    IF(
      MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 0,
      (arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] + arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]) / 2,
      arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]
    )
  FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x) AS arr FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x)
));

SELECT
    date,
    user_id,
    revenue,
    MEDIAN(
      ARRAY_AGG(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
      ORDER BY datetime_diff(date, date('2000-01-01'), day) 
      RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  ) AS median_last_5_days   
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
GROUP BY date, user_id, revenue
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Sample data:

[image]

Output:

[image]